# Flush mount a drop-in sink

Tags: kitchen-sink

I want to put a drop-in sink with a 1" wide 1/32" (or so) thick lip.
I want to mount it flush with the countertop (quartzite).

I'm thinking asking the fabricator to mill a 1/32" deep notch around the sink and then use side-grinder to grind the sink so it would fit into that groove (I'd imagine it is easier to grind down sink than it is to mill the stone perfectly).

Two questions:

1. is it realistic to cut the stone with that much precision?
2. what material should I use to fill the gap between the stone and the sink? I'd imagine it would need to be an epoxy resin of some sort. Any recommendations?

I imagine that the metal shouldn't actually be touching the stone (horizontally, obviously the sink will be sitting on the stone), because of the difference in thermal expansion rates.

Is it something that's being commonly done?

(here is the sink: https://www.homedepot.com/p/16-Gauge-Stainless-Steel-33-in-Single-Bowl-Undermount-or-Drop-In-Kitchen-Sink-with-Splash-Deck-and-Offset-Drain-SD178411/315448941)

Comment: No, one commonly buys an undermount sink and undermounts it (an option for you based on the title of your link), or a "sink and countertop molded as one object" if going for the utterly seamless look, or mounts a top mount sink on top. It's definitely **not** "commonly being done." For, IMHO, good reasons.

Comment: This might do better split up into multiple questions. I think this might be safely within the capabilities of many fabricators/countertop shops, etc. I can't speak to how popular your method might be, but the manufacturer indicates using silicone sealant under the lip of the sink to seal it.

Comment: We don't know the tolerances of your contractor's equipment, so we wouldn't be able to tell you if he can mill to an accuracy of 1/32". You'll have to ask him.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think any stone fabricator will want to take this project on the way you have outlined it. The tolerances are too tight and grinding down the metal on the sink is a bad idea.

How about routing the 1/32" sink flange into your wooden subtop (the wood on top of the cabinets that you countertop will sit on) so it sits flush with the subtop. Then they cut the proper hole and polish/ finish the edge there. This is standard fare for undermount sinks.

Comment: Another way, cut a piece of plywood that sits in the subtop, and has been cutout to fit the sink and cover the flange.  You can get sink brackets that tighten that up to the counter when assembled.